# Caesar's Cipher rotate with all possible combinations

Tags: java

In this program method `encode` and `decode` are working, but I have to include a third method `rotation`. The user has to type in a decode word, for example `"eadaf eals"` and the program uses the algorithm `decode` to show all 25 possibiliies.

**For example:**

```
Rotation     text
1            eadaf eal  //original text from user
2            eolwk wkk
3            hello you
....
25           klsjd ddk
```

But I have problems with the last method. There has to be a `for` loop for all 25 
possibilities.

```
public class CaesarsChiffre {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char benutzerBefehl;
        String benutzerText;
        int rotation=0;


        System.out.println("Caesars Chiffre encode, decode, rotate.");
        System.out.println("Waehlen Sie:");
        System.out.println("V for encode");
        System.out.println("E for decode");
        System.out.println("B for rotation");
        benutzerBefehl=Input.readChar();

        switch (benutzerBefehl){ 
        case 'V':   System.out.println("Enter text to encode:");
                    benutzerText=Input.readString();

                    System.out.println("which rotation do you want?");
                    rotation=Input.readInt();
                      while (rotation < 1 || rotation > 25) {
                          System.out.println(" The key must be between 1 and 25, you entered: "+ benutzerBefehl);
                          break;
                          }
                    System.out.print("Encoded text: ");
                    System.out.println(Caesarencode(benutzerText,rotation));
        break;
        case 'E':   System.out.println("Enter text to decode:");
                    benutzerText=Input.readString();

                    System.out.println("which rotation do you want?");
                    rotation=Input.readInt();
                      while (rotation < 1 || rotation > 25) {
                          System.out.println(" The key must be between 1 and 25, you entered: "+ benutzerBefehl);
                          break;
                      }
                     System.out.println("Decoded Text :");
                     System.out.println(Caesardecode(benutzerText,rotation));
        break;
        case 'B':       System.out.println("Enter the rotated text:");
                        benutzerText=Input.readString();
                        System.out.println("Rotation        Text: ");
                        System.out.println(Caesardecode(benutzerText));

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option..");
        }

    }

        public static String Caesarencode(String original_text, int rot){

            int length =original_text.length();
            String cypherText="";

            for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                char  ch=original_text.charAt(i);
                    if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
                        if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)){
                            char c=(char)(ch+rot);
                            if(c>'z'){
                                cypherText += (char)(ch-(26-rot));
                            }
                            else{
                                cypherText+=c;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
                            char c=(char)(ch+rot);
                            if(c>'Z'){
                                cypherText += (char)(ch-(26-rot));
                            }
                            else{
                            cypherText += c;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        cypherText+=ch;
                    }
            }
            return cypherText;
        }
        public static String Caesardecode(String original_text, int rot){

            int length =original_text.length();
            String cypherText="";

            for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                char  ch=original_text.charAt(i);
                    if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
                        if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)){
                            char c=(char)(ch-rot);
                            if(c<'a'){
                                cypherText += (char)(ch+(26-rot));
                            }
                            else{
                                cypherText+=c;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
                            char c=(char)(ch-rot);
                            if(c<'A'){
                                cypherText += (char)(ch+(26-rot));
                            }
                            else{
                            cypherText += c;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        cypherText+=ch;
                    }
            }
            return cypherText.toString();
        }

    public static String[] Caesardecode(String secret_text){  


    String[] textNeu= new String[25];  //problems with this part

    for(int i=0;i<textNeu.length;i++){

        textNeu[i]= Caesardecode(secret_text, i)+" ";

    }
    return textNeu;
    }
}
```

Comment: `javascript !== java`

Comment: please fix your tags. as above comment.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ? What is the problem exactly ? PS : I found your code really complicated. To doa Ceasar with only 26 letter, you just need to convert the `char` into a number from 0 to 25 (`c` - `a`) increment the value and do a `% 26` on it. To get back the `char`, add `a` at the end. This is only a few lines. Same for Uppercase.

Comment: "problems with this part" what problem?

Comment: This is the actual output: [Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742
Invalid option..

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you are print an array

```
 System.out.println(Caesardecode(benutzerText));
```

As you can see

```
 public static String[] Caesardecode(String secret_text){
```

you need to `Arrays.toString(array)` to get something more readable.

For the *invalid option* is because you forgot the `break` statement at the end of the `case`

```
case 'B':       System.out.println("Enter the rotated text:");
                benutzerText=Input.readString();
                System.out.println("Rotation        Text: ");
                System.out.println(Caesardecode(benutzerText));
    break; // ADD IT HERE
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid option..");
    }
```

---

Just because you have already done a lot of thing, here is a cleaner solution using a method taking a parameter for the increment.

I clean the code a bit, used some `Character` method that you missed (is lower/upper case.

But most important, the usage of `%26` to allow a `z` + 1 to become a `a`

```
public static String ceasar(String s, int inc){
    char[] input = s.toCharArray();
    char[] output = new char[input.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < output.length; ++i){
        char c = input[i];

        if(Character.isAlphabetic(c)){
            char a;
            if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
                a = 'A';
            } else if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
                a = 'a';
            } else { //not a letter, no evaluation needed
                output[i] = input[i];
                continue;
            }
            //encode the letter
            output[i] = (char)(((c - a + inc) % 26) + a);
        } else {
            output[i] = input[i];
        }
    }
    return new String(output);
}
```

You can easily put that into a loop to call

```
for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i){
    ceasar("youCode", i);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i still don´t understand the last  method.